# str() shows USArrests tohave 4 columns, but it has 5. Why is this present & part of downstream analysis but not in str()

Tags: r, dataframe

The structure function in R shows that USArrests only has 4 variables.
However, there are 5. State names are in the first column however it is unlabeled.

I am struggling to understand the intuition behind this and how this works.
I have done a K-means clustering algorithm with the data and it seems that the first column(state names) acts as labels in the analysis. Without being used a categorical data.
this is the tutorial I used.
https://uc-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering

Below is some code to explain myself in a clearer manner.

```
str(USArrests)
```

```
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Murder  : num  13.2 10 8.1 8.8 9 7.9 3.3 5.9 15.4 17.4 ...
 $ Assault : int  236 263 294 190 276 204 110 238 335 211 ...
 $ UrbanPop: int  58 48 80 50 91 78 77 72 80 60 ...
 $ Rape    : num  21.2 44.5 31 19.5 40.6 38.7 11.1 15.8 31.9 25.8 ...
```

```
head(USArrests)
```

```
           Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape
Alabama      13.2     236       58 21.2
Alaska       10.0     263       48 44.5
Arizona       8.1     294       80 31.0
Arkansas      8.8     190       50 19.5
California    9.0     276       91 40.6
Colorado      7.9     204       78 38.7
```

How it looks as "label" in the K Means Clustering

```
library(tidyverse)  # data manipulation
library(cluster)    # clustering algorithms
```

## Data Cleaning

```
df <- USArrests
df <- na.omit(df)
```

## Scaling

```
(df <- scale(df))
```

## Compute K-means Clustering

```
k2 <- kmeans(df, centers = 2, nstart = 25)
```

## Sample Output

```
Clustering vector:
       Alabama         Alaska        Arizona       Arkansas     California  
             2              2              2              1              2
```

If there are only four variables how does R, or the clustering algorithm know to associate the cluster with the state name, which technically isn't a column?

Comment: `c(Alabama, Alaska, ...)` is not a column in the dataset. It's a vector of rownames. You can access it with `rownames(USArrests)`.

Comment: Thank for this. However, when a dataframe does not have an assigned index and is just (1:n) how do you use a column to act as the index?

Comment: Did you mean to post your comment as a response to the answer by Manas Sarmah below? Because I don't think they'll get a notification unless the comment is posted under the answer (instead of under your question)...

Answer (score 2):

The first "column" is not actually a column but the index to the dataset. Instead of the index being 1,2,3,4, etc. like default, it is Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, etc. Which is why running the str() function gives us only 4 columns as an index is never treated as a column.

Now, the clustering output showed which cluster each state belonged to. This is simply the index and the algorithm at the end is telling us which cluster each row belongs to. For example, if the index was 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. instead of state names, we would still get the result as row 1 being cluster 2, row 2 being in cluster 2, row 3 being in cluster 2,row 4 being in cluster 1, etc. The algorithm does what you tell it to do. It sees the index and labels the respective cluster against that index.
Hope this helps.